# Assembly - calculating arithmetic mean - segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, 32-bit

I'm supposed to solve this problem, where I am supposed to **calculate the arithmetic mean** of x (6) numbers using the **CDECL convention**:

The function in C looks like this: **`float average(const float *array, long N, float (*f)(float), long *error);`**

```
section .data
    array dd 1.5,-100.0,30.0,1.0,-1.0,90.0
    array_len dd 6
    error dd -1

section .text
average:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    ; condition if array is empty
    cmp [ebp+8], dword 0
    je .array_zero

    ; condition if array_len is 0
    cmp [ebp+12], dword 0
    jle .count_zero

    ; condition if passed function is null
    cmp [ebp+16], dword 0
    je .function_zero

    ; preserving registers
    push esi
    push edi

    mov esi, [ebp+8]
    mov ecx, [ebp+12]

    ; define-ing Quiet NaN (used as a error return value)
    QNAN EQU 0x7FFFFFFF
    MASK_IS_NAN EQU 0000_0001_0000_0000b

    ; applying the user-defined function on the numbers
.loop:
    push ecx
    lodsd
    push eax
    call dword [ebp+16] ; the pointer to the function is at this address
    add esp, 4
    pop ecx

    fxam
    fstsw ax
    and ax, 0100_0101_0000_0000b
    cmp ax, MASK_IS_NAN
    je .is_not_a_number

    fstp dword [edi + ecx*4 - 4] ; storing the number in edi register
    loop .loop

    ; calculating the arithmetic average
    mov ecx, [ebp+12]
    fld dword [edi + ecx*4 - 4] 
    dec ecx

.calc:
    fld dword [edi + ecx*4 - 4]
    fadd
    loop .calc

    fild dword [ebp+12]

    fdiv ; the result of the arithmetic average is as defined in CDECL in st0 FPU register
    ; setting error = 0 and exiting
    mov [ebp+20], dword 0
    jmp .exit

.is_not_a_number:
    mov [ebp+20], dword 8
    jmp .error

.array_zero:
    cmp [ebp+12], dword 0
    jle .array_count_zero
    cmp [ebp+16], dword 0
    je .array_function_zero

    mov [ebp+20], dword 1
    jmp .error

.count_zero:
    cmp [ebp+8], dword 0
    je .array_count_zero
    cmp [ebp+16], dword 0
    je .count_function_zero

    mov [ebp+20], dword 2
    jmp .error

.function_zero:
    mov [ebp+20], dword 4
    jmp .error

.array_count_zero:
    cmp [ebp+16], dword 0
    je .all_zero

    mov [ebp+20], dword 3
    jmp .error

.array_function_zero:
    cmp [ebp+12], dword 0
    jle .all_zero

    mov [ebp+20], dword 5
    jmp .error

.count_function_zero:
    cmp [ebp+8], dword 0
    je .all_zero

    mov [ebp+20], dword 6
    jmp .error

.all_zero:
    mov [ebp+20], dword 7
    jmp .error

.error:
    push dword QNAN
    fld dword [esp]
    add esp,4
    jmp .exit

.exit:
    pop edi
    pop esi
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

fn_example:
    finit
    fld dword [esp+4]
    xor ecx,-1
    xor edx,-1
    xor eax,-1
    ret

CMAIN:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    sub esp,4

    ; un-mask FPU exceptions
    fstcw [esp]
    and [esp],word 1111_1111_1110_0000b
    fldcw [esp]
    
    push error
    push fn_example
    push dword [array_len]
    push array
    call average
    add esp,16

    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

I am getting a segmentation fault on the hosted server, where the results are checked, but on my local device, it's working fine.

Any ideas, why the segfault might be caused?

Comment: How does it get built and run on the server that checks it?  Built into a static Linux executable, execution starts at the top of `.text`, so it tries to `ret` to EIP = `argc = 1`, faulting, because clearly it's not designed to be run that way.  Or if I put a `main:` / `global main` at `CMAIN:` and link it with `gcc -m32 -no-pie foo.o` then I get a segfault on `fstp   DWORD [edi+ecx*4-0x4]` in `average.loop`, trying to access address 0x14.  (EDI=0, ECX=6).  (Assembling with `nasm -felf32`  of course.)

Comment: @PeterCordes That's a question I'd like to know the answer to, as well. We don't know how the server-sided compiler works, but I can guess it starts from CMAIN: then `call(s) average` and goes to my function, since the only thing I had to program was the `average: ret` block. How can I reproduce the segfault at `fstp DWORD [edi+ecx*4-4]`? I am using the Debugging feature in VSCode and for me, it does not return segfault even after all 6 values are loaded in EDI register.

Comment: I built it into a Linux executable since that's what I'm using and you didn't say what OS it was for.  `nasm -felf32` / gcc 11.1 `-m32 -no-pie` linking with GNU Binutils `ld` 2.36.1, if different defaults in different toolchain versions affect layout of data / .text.  It's a Linux 5.16 kernel.  (I didn't look through the source code in detail since it's pretty long.)  If your function isn't looking at memory above its stack frame, or outside what's in `section .data`, details like non-executable stack and read-only .text, and linker layout of sections, shouldn't matter.

Comment: If you can reduce it to a smaller [mcve] that still faults on the test server, that would be better.  IDK if you have limited attempts, though.  If you can use a debugger on the test server, that would be ideal.

Comment: Sorry, I am using `nasm -felf32 -F dwarf -g` and `gcc -m32 -ggdb` and basically what I'm doing is getting the number from the array, applying the (*f)(float) function on it, storing it in the EDI register and when I have all the numbers in EDI, I let another loop to add them together in FPU and then divide the number by the N (length) of the array to get the arithmetic mean.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. On my laptop running Ubuntu I just can not get the segfault. And additionally, I can not use the debugger on the test server, nor can I see what are the results. (no limited attempts, tho)

Comment: Ok, so you could maybe reduce this to a much smaller and simpler program that just reproduces the crash there but not on your machine, without trying to fully solve the problem, just a [mre] of the segfault itself that's small enough for experts to look at all of it.  How old is the toolchain on your local machine; does it not default to PIE and warn you `foo.o: warning: relocation in read-only section `.text'` / `warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE` when you link with GCC without using `-no-pie`?

Comment: gcc (9.4.0) and nasm (2.14.02). Debug console after compiling writes nothing and running writes: [Inferior 1 (process 3417) exited normally] The program 'task1' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000). I don't really know how to create the minimal reproducible example since I always need to include the whole code on the server.

Comment: *I always need to include the whole code on the server.* - Save your current code in a file somewhere, and start cutting out parts of it (e.g. remove a loop, remove a function call, but in ways that make it still not crash locally).  So the "whole code" that's left is more minimal, and you can test it on the server.  [this](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) has some suggestions on how to make a MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out that the EDI register (`fld dword [edi + ecx*4 - 4]`) was causing the segfault since it was not malloc-ed. The weird thing is that in the VSCode debugger it was working properly, but the server-sided compiler had a problem with this.

What I added to the code:

```
...
mov esi, [ebp+8]
mov ecx, [ebp+12]

; ADDED SNIPET
lea eax, [ecx*4]
push eax
EXTERN malloc
call malloc
add esp, 4
mov edi, eax

mov ecx, [ebp+12]
; ADDED SNIPPET

; define-ing Quiet NaN (used as a error return value)
QNAN EQU 0x7FFFFFFF
...
```

Comment: Are you maybe reading before the beginning of `array`?  On Linux+glibc, `malloc` return values are usually 16 bytes from the start of a page, at least.  But modern toolchains (like on my desktop or your server) will put `.data` right at the start of a page (instead of overlapping some metadata and/or code into the same mapping), so `array:` will be at the start of a page, and access to `[array-4]` will fault.

Comment: Or was that actually supposed to be separate scratch space?  Oh right, when it crashed for me, EDI was `0`, so I guess not off the beginning of the array.  Arithmetic mean of an array doesn't need any scratch space, just a running total, unless you're doing something like [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) to reduce rounding error over huge arrays without recursion.  The x87 stack of st0..7 is plenty of space to work with.  Or a fixed amount of stack space if you want your callback to run `finit`, perhaps because you didn't balance the FP register stack!

Comment: Well, the `fn_example` function was used there just to mess with my `FPU stack` and `EAX, ECX, EDX registers`. It was part of the assignment because as mentioned, the CDECL convention expects a clean FPU stack, so they used a function to "`finit`" the FPU stack every time you called the function with your current number